# Mod_security2 and clamav to catch malicious files on upload

Tags: upload, mod-security, clamav, anti-virus

Is there a clear documentation to describe the solution?

It's very common and also necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this blogpost](http://www.howtoforge.de/anleitung/installation-von-modsecurity2-auf-debian-etch/) is useful for you. It explains how to setup modsecurity2 with apache on debian BUT it is written in german. It should be understandable if you only read the "commands" which are in english anyway.

1. Update your sources.list
2. apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
3. vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

   Add the following:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_security2.c>
   # Basic configuration options
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecResponseBodyAccess Off

   # Handling of file uploads
   # TODO Choose a folder private to Apache.
   # SecUploadDir /opt/apache-frontend/tmp/
   SecUploadKeepFiles Off
   ```
4. Restart apache /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: unwichtich, could you please add details on running clamav on uploaded files?